# Intersection Observer not working on image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I learned that images need different intersection observer code than text to work. I changed the code and now my intersection observer works very strangely. When I scroll down it stays (opacity: 0), but when scroll up and back down it works. Then when I scroll up and back down another time it stays (opacity: 1). I'm trying to get the image to fade into the screen. Thanks in advance!

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Mynerve&family=Nunito&family=Open+Sans&family=Poppins&family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"></head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <header class='header'>
        <img src="images/bgImage.png" alt="Not Loading..." class="bgImage">
        <div class="bgImageScreen"></div>
        <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Not Loading..." class="logo" width="150px" height="40px">
        <div class="title">Build Your<br>Business</div>
        <div class="subText">Work with experts to create and grow<br>your business.</div>
        <a href="#section1"><div class="learnMore"><h3>Learn More</h3></div></a>
        </header>
        <section class="section1" id="section1">
            <div class="businessTitle hidden">80% of Business Fail</div>
            <div class="businessText hidden">Start up businesses fail all around the world. 
                The majority of times, the business lacks funding, market research, and is poorly planned. 
                Failure could also stem from the founder having unrealistic expectations about the future of the business. 
                This has become an issue, for businesses drive economic growth.
                Here at Trelp, we've addressed this issue, and have found a perfect solution. 
                </div>
            <img data-lazy="images/business.png" alt="Not Loading..." class="img"> 
        </section>
        <section class="section2">
            <div class="expertSec">
                <div class="title2">Advising from Experts</div>
                <div class="subText2">Struggling and need help to create your business, no problem.</div>
                <div class="bullets">
                    <div class="bp hidden1">Experts work with you to expand and inovate your business idea.</div>
                    <div class="bp hidden1">Help from experts on designing your product or service.</div>
                    <div class="bp hidden1">Advice from experts on selling your product.</div>
                    <div class="bp hidden1">Experts available 24/7 for 1 on 1 meetings.</div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
    <script defer src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}


a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

:root {
    --black: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    --white: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.container {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    perspective: 10px;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.bgImage {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    object-fit: cover;
    transform: translateZ(-10px) scale(2);
}

.bgImageScreen {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 102%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 102%;
    object-fit: cover;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.626), black);
    transform: translateZ(-10px) scale(2);
}

header {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    z-index: -1;
}

.logo {
    margin: 20px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 1470px;
    z-index: 3;
}

.title {
    color: var(--white);
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 90px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 1400px;
    left: 120px;
    line-height: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.subText {
    color: var(--white);
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 1400px;
    left: 120px;
}

.learnMore {
    width: 180px;
    height: 70px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 1400px;
    left: 120px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    margin-top: 30px;
    border: 3px solid var(--white);
    background-color: var(--white);
    color: var(--black);
    border-radius: 15px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    transition: all 1s;
}

.learnMore:hover {
    color: var(--white);
    background-color: transparent;
}

.section1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 115vh;
    background: var(--black);
    margin: 0px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 27px;
}

.hidden {
    opacity: 0;
    filter: blur(2px);
    transition: all 2s;
}

@media(prefers-reduced-motion) {
    .hidden {
        transform: none;
        transition: none;
    }
}

.show {    
    opacity: 1;
    filter: blur(0);
}

.img {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 400px;
    left: 750px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 1s;
}

.fade {
    opacity: 1;
}

.businessTitle {
    color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-size: 40px;
    position: relative;
    top: 150px;
    left: 150px;
    margin: 30px;
    width: 500px;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.businessText {
    color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-size: 25px;
    width: 500px;
    position: relative;
    top: 150px;
    left: 150px;
    line-height: 40px;
    margin: 30px;
}

.section2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 140vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.expertSec {
    height: 75%;
    width: 80%;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;
}

.title2 {
    font-size: 60px;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    top: 30px;
    margin: 30px 0px;
    text-align: center;
}

.subText2 {
    font-size: 30px;
    color: rgb(92, 92, 92);
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}

.bullets {
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    font-size: 25px;
    position: relative;
    top: 30px;
}

.bp {
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: 900px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Poppins';
    border-radius: 20px;
}

.hidden1 {
    opacity: 0;
    filter: blur(5px);
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    transition: all 1.5s;
}

@media(prefers-reduced-motion) {
    .hidden1 {
        transition: none;
    }
    
}

.show1 {
    filter: blur(0);
    transform: translateX(0%);
    opacity: 1;
}
```

JavaScript

```
//For section1 text
const observer = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
    entries.forEach(entry => {
        if (entry.intersectionRatio >= 0.25) {
            entry.target.classList.add('show')
        } else {
            entry.target.classList.remove('show')
        }
    }) 
}, {threshold: [0.25]})

const hiddenElement = document.querySelectorAll('.hidden')
hiddenElement.forEach(el => observer.observe(el))

//For section2 bullet points
const observer1 = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
    entries.forEach(entry => {
        if (entry.intersectionRatio >= 0.1) {
            entry.target.classList.add('show1')
        } else {
            entry.target.classList.remove('show1')
        }
    }) 
}, {threshold: [0.1]})

const hiddenElement1 = document.querySelectorAll('.hidden1')
hiddenElement1.forEach(el => observer1.observe(el))

//For businessImage lazy load

const targets = document.querySelectorAll('.img')

const lazyLoad = target => {
    const io = new IntersectionObserver((entries, observer) => {
        entries.forEach(entry => {
            console.log("bruh")
            if(entry.intersectionRatio >= 0.25) {
                const img = entry.target
                const src = img.getAttribute('data-lazy')

                img.setAttribute('src', src)
                img.classList.add('fade')

                observer.disconnect()
            }
        })
    })
    io.observe(target)
}

targets.forEach(lazyLoad)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }


        a {
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        :root {
            --black: rgb(0, 0, 0);
            --white: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        }

        .container {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            overflow-y: auto;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            height: 100vh;
            width: 100%;
            perspective: 10px;
            scroll-behavior: smooth;
        }

        .bgImage {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100vh;
            object-fit: cover;
            transform: translateZ(-10px) scale(2);
        }

        .bgImageScreen {
            position: relative;
            bottom: 102%;
            width: 100%;
            height: 102%;
            object-fit: cover;
            background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.626), black);
            transform: translateZ(-10px) scale(2);
        }

        header {
            position: relative;
            height: 100%;
            transform-style: preserve-3d;
            z-index: -1;
        }

        .logo {
            margin: 20px;
            position: relative;
            bottom: 1470px;
            z-index: 3;
        }

        .title {
            color: var(--white);
            font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
            font-size: 90px;
            position: relative;
            bottom: 1400px;
            left: 120px;
            line-height: 100px;
            margin-bottom: 30px;
        }

        .subText {
            color: var(--white);
            font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
            font-size: 30px;
            position: relative;
            bottom: 1400px;
            left: 120px;
        }

        .learnMore {
            width: 180px;
            height: 70px;
            position: relative;
            bottom: 1400px;
            left: 120px;
            font-size: 20px;
            font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
            margin-top: 30px;
            border: 3px solid var(--white);
            background-color: var(--white);
            color: var(--black);
            border-radius: 15px;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            transition: all 1s;
        }

        .learnMore:hover {
            color: var(--white);
            background-color: transparent;
        }

        .section1 {
            width: 100%;
            height: 115vh;
            background: var(--black);
            margin: 0px;
            position: relative;
            bottom: 27px;
        }

        .hidden {
            opacity: 0;
            filter: blur(2px);
            transition: all 2s;
        }

        @media(prefers-reduced-motion) {
            .hidden {
                transform: none;
                transition: none;
            }
        }

        .show {
            opacity: 1;
            filter: blur(0);
        }

        .img {
            position: relative;
            bottom: 400px;
            /* left: 750px; */
            left: 300px;
            /* width: 300px;
      height:400px;
      object-fit: cover; */
            border-radius: 20px;
            opacity: 0;
            transition: all 1s;
        }

        .fade {
            opacity: 1;
        }

        .businessTitle {
            color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
            font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
            font-size: 40px;
            position: relative;
            top: 150px;
            left: 150px;
            margin: 30px;
            width: 500px;
            font-weight: 700;
        }

        .businessText {
            color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
            font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
            font-size: 25px;
            width: 500px;
            position: relative;
            top: 150px;
            left: 150px;
            line-height: 40px;
            margin: 30px;
        }

        .section2 {
            width: 100%;
            height: 140vh;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
        }

        .expertSec {
            height: 75%;
            width: 80%;
            box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
            position: relative;
            top: 100px;
        }

        .title2 {
            font-size: 60px;
            font-weight: 900;
            font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
            position: relative;
            top: 30px;
            margin: 30px 0px;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .subText2 {
            font-size: 30px;
            color: rgb(92, 92, 92);
            position: relative;
            top: 10px;
            font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .bullets {
            display: grid;
            place-items: center;
            font-size: 25px;
            position: relative;
            top: 30px;
        }

        .bp {
            margin: 20px;
            padding: 20px;
            border: 2px solid black;
            width: 900px;
            text-align: center;
            font-family: 'Poppins';
            border-radius: 20px;
        }

        .hidden1 {
            opacity: 0;
            filter: blur(5px);
            transform: translateX(-100%);
            transition: all 1.5s;
        }

        @media(prefers-reduced-motion) {
            .hidden1 {
                transition: none;
            }

        }

        .show1 {
            filter: blur(0);
            transform: translateX(0%);
            opacity: 1;
        }
    </style>
    <link
        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Mynerve&family=Nunito&family=Open+Sans&family=Poppins&family=Roboto&display=swap"
        rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <header class='header'>
            <img src="https://platinumlist.net/guide/wp-content/uploads/2023/03/IMG-worlds-of-adventure.webp"
                alt="Not Loading..." class="bgImage">
            <div class="bgImageScreen"></div>
            <img src="https://platinumlist.net/guide/wp-content/uploads/2023/03/IMG-worlds-of-adventure.webp"
                alt="Not Loading..." class="logo" width="150px" height="40px">
            <div class="title">Build Your<br>Business</div>
            <div class="subText">Work with experts to create and grow<br>your business.</div>
            <a href="#section1">
                <div class="learnMore">
                    <h3>Learn More</h3>
                </div>
            </a>
        </header>
        <section class="section1" id="section1">
            <div class="businessTitle hidden">80% of Business Fail</div>
            <div class="businessText hidden">Start up businesses fail all around the world.
                The majority of times, the business lacks funding, market research, and is poorly planned.
                Failure could also stem from the founder having unrealistic expectations about the future of the
                business.
                This has become an issue, for businesses drive economic growth.
                Here at Trelp, we've addressed this issue, and have found a perfect solution.
            </div>

        </section>
        <img data-lazy="https://platinumlist.net/guide/wp-content/uploads/2023/03/IMG-worlds-of-adventure.webp"
            alt="Not Loading..." class="img">
        <section class="section2">
            <div class="expertSec">
                <div class="title2">Advising from Experts</div>
                <div class="subText2">Struggling and need help to create your business, no problem.</div>
                <div class="bullets">
                    <div class="bp hidden1">Experts work with you to expand and inovate your business idea.</div>
                    <div class="bp hidden1">Help from experts on designing your product or service.</div>
                    <div class="bp hidden1">Advice from experts on selling your product.</div>
                    <div class="bp hidden1">Experts available 24/7 for 1 on 1 meetings.</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
    <script>
        //For section1 text
        const observer = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
            entries.forEach(entry => {
                if (entry.intersectionRatio >= 0.25) {
                    entry.target.classList.add('show')
                } else {
                    entry.target.classList.remove('show')
                }
            })
        }, { threshold: [0.25] })

        const hiddenElement = document.querySelectorAll('.hidden')
        hiddenElement.forEach(el => observer.observe(el))

        //For section2 bullet points
        const observer1 = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
            entries.forEach(entry => {
                if (entry.intersectionRatio >= 0.1) {
                    entry.target.classList.add('show1')
                } else {
                    entry.target.classList.remove('show1')
                }
            })
        }, { threshold: [0.1] })

        const hiddenElement1 = document.querySelectorAll('.hidden1')
        hiddenElement1.forEach(el => observer1.observe(el))

        //For businessImage lazy load

        const targets = document.querySelectorAll('.img')

        const lazyLoad = target => {
            const io = new IntersectionObserver((entries, observer) => {
                entries.forEach(entry => {
                    // The image element is set to left: 700px. When a large area of the image is outside the screen, the intersection area between it and the document and the element becomes less, making it difficult to reach the intersection trigger condition. Therefore, it is set to left: 300px
                    console.log("bruh", entry.intersectionRatio)
                    const img = entry.target

                    if (entry.intersectionRatio >= 0.25) { // when intersection >= 0.25, add fade class

                        const src = img.getAttribute('data-lazy')

                        img.setAttribute('src', src)
                        if (!img.classList.contains('fade')) {
                            img.classList.add('fade')
                        }
                        // can't exec disconnect, because we need to still observe img intersection area
                        // observer.disconnect()
                    } else {
                        if (img.classList.contains('fade')) {// remove fade class

                            img.classList.remove('fade')
                        }
                    }
                })
            }, {
                threshold: [0, 0.25, 0.5, 1] // 
            })
            io.observe(target)
        }

        targets.forEach(lazyLoad)
    </script>
</body>

</html>`
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code.